# Enable tinyMce on all the nodes except one

Tags: drupal, tinymce

```
node/*
user/*
comment/*
```

This is what I am using to enable tinyMCE Drupal on particular pages.

Now what I am looking for is to apply on all the NODES except the one having id (eg 100). How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [WYISWYG API](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) module and input formats.

Make an input format called Node100, which is a clone of the usual input format what you use for nodes. Do not enable TinyMCE on that input format. Set the input format for that node.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

http://drupal.org/node/121331

It goes into depth on how to enable TinyMCE. I believe there is a Drupal admin setting for doing what you want.